# Creating a merge after creating a secondary branch in github

Tags: git, github

I created a secondary branch using `git checkout -b your-branch-name`

Then I changed the title in the html around. How do I merge those two branches so I can see a conflict if the same line of code is different?

Carolyn@LAPTOP-7G9JKKU2 MINGW64 ~/projects/portfolio (master)
$ git checkout -b ctevnan-patch-1
Switched to a new branch 'ctevnan-patch-1'
(I changed the title and committed the changes using the commit changes button)

Answer (score 1):

I would switch back to master, i.e. `git checkout master` then run `git merge ctevnan-patch-1`.

Comment: Thank you eabates! Github gave me the following instructions: use the command line to resolve conflicts and perform a manual merge. STEP1- From your project repository (I assume this means switch back to master) bring in the changes and test. git fetch origin   git checkout -b ctevnan-patch-1 origin/ctevnan-patch-1    git merge alex branch     STEP 2: merge the changes and update on github :  git checkout alex-branch git merge --no-ff ctevnan-patch-1   git push origin alex-branch .   Sound about right?